# existence of a permutation that satisfies order-constraints

Tags: permutations, constraint-satisfaction, ordering

I would like to know if there is a simple algorithm for checking the existence of a permutation that satisfies a number of order-constraints.

For example, suppose we have a set (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and a number of constraints:

- 1 should be before 2
- 2 should be before 4
- 4 should be before 1

(which is of course infeasible).

Is there a simple algorithm for checking the feasibility of order-constraints? (that does not rely on lp-solvers)?

I do not have anything against Lp-solving, but i suspect that simpler algorithms are available.

Comment: You *may* be interested in Contraint programming (which is **not** the same as linear programming, but a superset). in particular you are interested in the algorithm for *constraint propagation* of binary contraints.  Try searching a bit these terms and you will find some notions about consistency and some general algorithms, and also some interesting special cases (e.g. propagation of the "all different" constraint, which makes use of the maximal matching problem).

Answer (score 5):

Yes. ​ That task is called [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Algorithms).

Comment: thank you very much, that was exactly what i wanted to know!